# Derivative of piecewise functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was going through some solved examples when I came across this sum.[image]

My doubt is that while calculating the derivative of the function at 0 why has the right hand derivative (that is the right hand function only has been considered for derivative evaluation at x=0) been considered and not the left hand derivative? And in piecewise functions like this why do we have to find the derivative at 0 separately by using the limit definition of derivative?

Comment: To make the slopes match up on both sides of $x=0$ which they do here so the derivative does exist at $x=0$. Example where they don't match up ... is $g(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$ so $g'$ wouldn't exist at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As told by @randomgirl, the slope is matching at $x=0$, so, no matter which side function you take it will give you same result. The nice example $g(x)=|x|$ in which slope on both sides of $x=0$ do not matches is also given by randomgirl.

See the graph of both functions around $x=0$. The both functions $x\,{\rm e}^{3x}$ and $x+3x^{2}-x^{3}$ are tangential to each other at $x=0$.(where $a=3$ is taken for example sake)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We define **Right Hand Derivative** of $f(x)$ to be derivative of $f(x)$ as $x \to0^{+}$, or as $x\to0$ from right side. As $x\to 0$ from right, it is obvious that the right hand definition, or definition for $x > 0$ has to be used.

Similarly, **Left Hand Derivative** of $f(x)$ is derivative of $f(x)$ as $x \to0^{-}$, or as $x\to0$ from left side. Here $x\to 0$ from left, so we use the definition $x < 0$.

The function is differentiable at $x = 0\iff \mathbf{LHD = RHD} = f'(0)$

In your case, all the evaluate to $1$, so the function is differentiable at $x = 0$